# PHP array only prints first letter of each item

Tags: arrays, loops, printing

The code below is only printing the first letter of each array item. It's got me quite baffled.

```
require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';
print_r($site->bookmarkTags(1));

$index = 0;
foreach ($site->bookmarkTags(1) as $tag) {
    echo $tag['$index'];
    $index = $index + 1;
}
```

print_r return:

```
Array ( [0] => Wallpapers [1] => Free )
```

the loop:

```
WF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try echo $tag, not $tag['$index']

Since you are using foreach, the value is already taken from the array, and when you post $tag['$index'] it will print the character from the '$index' position :)

Comment: Why does PHP even do that... or rather did. I'm aware they fixed it in 5.4+.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've attempted to do what foreach is already doing...
The problem is that you're actually echoing the $index letter of a non-array because foreach is already doing what you seem to be expecting your $index = $index+1 to do:

```
require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';
print_r($site->bookmarkTags(1));

$index = 0;
foreach ($site->bookmarkTags(1) as $tag) {
    echo $tag; // REMOVE [$index] from $tag, because $tag isn't an array
    $index = $index + 1; // You can remove this line, because it serves no purpose
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';

// Store the value temporarily instead of
// making a function call each time
$tags = $site->bookmarkTags(1);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag;
}
```

This should work. The issue might be because you're making a function call every iteration, versus storing the value temporarily and looping over it.