# Foreach returns only first letter of an array element?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, foreach

[There is almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050288/php-array-only-prints-first-letter-of-each-item), but I have no idea what to do in my case.

I'm just starting with OO PHP and I have this function within my class:

```
public function show() {
    foreach($this->data['fields'] as $field) {
        $type = $field['type'];
        echo $type;
    }
}
```

Here's the input data:

```
my_function('id', 
    array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => 'foo',
    'fields' => array(
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'etc.' => 'value'),
    ),
);
```

Of course `echo $field['type']` returns only the first letter of `my_type` (`m`).

And I can't just simply use `echo $field` as I have multiple keys under this array and it returns `my_typebarvalue` instead of `my_type`, the same happens with `$field[0]` (`mbv`). What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three key-value pairs in `$this->data['fields']`: `type => my_type`, `foo => bar` and `etc. => value`. When you use this `foreach` syntax, `$field` will contain *only* the value of the pair, which is always a string.

The index operator (the brackets after the variable, as in `$foo['bar']`) works on strings as well, and returns the character at the given index. Type juggling turns the string `'type'` into the integer `0`, and as such you get the first character of the string.

I'm not sure what you want, actually, if `echo $field` is not okay. PHP will not print newlines or separators unless asked, so you might want to try `echo $field . ' '` and see that the values are actually distinct.

Comment: I did `echo $field` and everything was clear after that! Brilliant answer, thanks a lot, this is how SO should look like (explaining things rather than giving direct answers/code). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over fields which is the following:

```
array(
   'type' => 'my_type',
   'foo' => 'bar',
   'etc.' => 'value'
)
```

using

```
foreach($this->data['fields'] as $field)
```

On each iteration, `$field` is already the values you are looking for (my_type, bar, value), so doing $field['type'], as @zneak mentioned, will get php to juggle 'type' to 0, hence you get the first character.

To get value when you are at type key, you can do the following:

```
public function show() {
    foreach($this->data['fields'] as $key => $field) {
        if($key == 'type') echo $field;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` will *iterate over all elements in `$data['fields']`*. On the first iteration, `$field` will be `"my_type"`, on the second iteration `$field` will be `"bar"` and so on. I.e., on each iteration, `$field` will be a string, not an array.

You will need an array of arrays for that loop to make sense, like:

```
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'etc.' => 'value',
    ),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array 'fields' is like:

```
    $fields['type'] = 'my_type';
    $fields['foo'] = 'bar';
    $fields['etc'] = 'value';
```

Means, that your array has only one dimension.
So access it like above.

In the foreach you tell php to go trough the keys (type, foo, ect). So $field is already (my_type, bar, value)!

```
// You either need to write:
foreach($this->data as $field) {
    $type = $field['fields']['type'];
    echo $type;
}

// Or
foreach($this->data['fields'] as $field) {
if ($field == 'type') {
        $type = $field;
        echo $type;
}
}

// Or
foreach($this->data['fields'] as $key => $val) {
if ($key == 'type') {
        $type = $val;
        echo $type;
}
}
```